# Function not defined although the function is definitely defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I play a bit with javascript XMLHttpRequest.

I wrote a function like this:

```
function setRequest(data){
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    if(!request){
        alert("Kann keine XMLHTTP-Instanz erzeugen");
        return false;
    }else{
        var url = "test.php";
        request.open('post', url, true);
        request.send('url'+data);
        //request.onreadystatechange = opendomain;
    }

}
$('a').attr("href", "javascript:setRequest('test')");
```

And with the last row I defined all links in my website to do the function setRequest();

My JS file is included in the footer and the jquery attr() works fine.
But when I click on a link I get the message that the function setRequest() is not defined.

But the function is defined?!

I do something wrong but can't see my issue.

Thanks for support.

Comment: Is this code directly within a `<script>` tag, or is it surrounded by anything else (eg a `$().ready`)?

Comment: second yes.. (function($){

Comment: Thank you! Sry for duplicate.